# Checking for key down on menu bar application

Tags: swift, popover, keyevent, menubar

I am writing a MacOS Menu Bar Application which uses a `popover`. I have relied on a number of tutorials to get things going.

Very briefly, the code looks something like this:

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var popover=NSPopover() 
    var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        //  Popover & Content View
            let contentView = ContentView()
            self.popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)

        //  Menu
            self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: 18)
            if let statusBarButton = self.statusBarItem.button {
                statusBarButton.title = "☰"
                statusBarButton.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))               
            }
    }
    
    @objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        let statusBarButton=self.statusBarItem.button!
        func show(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            self.popover.show(relativeTo: statusBarButton.bounds, of: statusBarButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
        }
        func hide(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            popover.performClose(sender)
        }
        self.popover.isShown ? hide(sender as AnyObject) : show(sender as AnyObject)
    }
}
```

How can I check whether the <kbd>option</kbd> key is down when the menu button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the current event whether the modifier flags contain `option`

```
func isOptionkeyPressed() -> Bool
{
    return NSApp.currentEvent?.modifierFlags.contains(.option) == true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `NSApp.currentEvent` was just the thing I needed.